# .htacces rewrite rule for one domain to another

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two domains
`domainone.com` and `domaintwo.com`
all files and codes are in `domainone.com`
now for a particular path in `domainone.com` I want the url to be of `domaintwo.com`

for say when `http://domainone.com/folder/param1/param2` url is accessed
I want the url in address bar to be `http://domaintwo.com/param1/param2`
but the content will come from `domainone.com` itself

what .htaccess rule I need to rewrite, I tried some of the rules but its not working as expected

Comment: No it is not possible without proxy from domain2 to domain1 in Apache config

Comment: Do you have access to Apache config on domain2?

Answer (score 0):

On `domain2` in your `httpd.conf` load peoxy modules like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Restart Apache after this.

Inside your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domaintwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://domain1.com/folder/$1/$2 [L,P]
```

On `domainone` inside your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://domain2.com/$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```